# Google Script to Match cell value and copy Paste related data in different tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Click here for [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sIaJqyLJcjt8iXu0mtNOC6CVjVVOOEMI4R1f32-w1zI/edit#gid=0)**

I need a solution that matches a cell value (Sheet1! Q5) to a range in another tab/sheet (NegotiationData! A1:O1) and paste the relevant data fetched from the first sheet under the designated columns of the second sheet under the matched value.

For example, if Sheet1!Q5 matches with the name in **NegotiationData! A1** then do the following

1. Fetch Sheet1! R6 and paste in NegotiationData!A3:A
2. Fetch Sheet1! Q6 and paste in NegotiationData!B3:B
3. Fetch Sheet1! Q7 and paste in NegotiationData!C3:C

Also, each time the script runs it should not overwrite data but find the next empty row and paste the values.

I have an incomplete script that I'm trying to achieve the above from my research from various posts but since I'm just a week old to coding I'm not able to go any further than where I have got with the below script. 
I'm not finding how to match the value and fetch the relevant data and paste them below the matched value.

Please help!

**The Incomplete / Incorrect Script (File Name: NegotiationSubmit)**

```
    function submitNegotiation() {
  var sh, id, v, estNum, negotiation, negoNotes, i;
  sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  id = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('Q5').getValue();
  v = sh.getRange('R6').getValue();
  estNum = Number(sh.getRange('Q6').getValue().split(" ")[1]);
  negoNotes = sh.getRange('Q7').getValue();
  negotiation =sh.getSheetByName('NegotiationData').getRange('A1:O');

  if(v && estNum) {
    negotiation.setValues(negotiation.getValues()
          .map(function (r, i) {
          if (r[0] == id) {
          r[1] = v;
          r[2] = estNum;
          r[3] = negoNotes;
          }
          return r;
          })
          )
  }
}
```

Comment: There was no error as the script is not complete in terms of achieving the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- Retrieve values of "Q5:R7" at once, and the values are converted to the import values.

  - Use the destructuring assignment for retrieving each value.
- Import the converted values using the number of column retrieved by `ids[0][i] == id`.

#### Modified script :

```
function submitNegotiation() {
  var id, estNum, v, negoNotes;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var values = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("Q5:R7").getValues();
  [id] = values[0];
  [estNum, v] = values[1];
  [negoNotes] = values[2];
//  estNum = Number(estNum.split(" ")[1]); // If you want to use "estNum = Number(sh.getRange('Q6').getValue().split(" ")[1]);", please use this line.
  var sh2 = sh.getSheetByName('NegotiationData');
  var ids = sh2.getRange("A1:O1").getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<ids[0].length; i++) {
    if (ids[0][i] == id) {
      sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, i + 1, 1, 3).setValues([[v, estNum, negoNotes]]);
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note :

I was confused to the following points.

- In your script, `estNum` is `Number(sh.getRange('Q6').getValue().split(" ")[1]);`. But in your sample spreadsheet, `Estimate 1` of cell "Q6" is used.

  - I commented this in modified script.
- In your sample spreadsheet, "Story ID" is `1`. But in your script, it's `US-001` of cell "R6".

  - In this modified script, `US-001` of cell "R6" was used.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

```
function submitNegotiation() {
  var id, estNum, v, negoNotes;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var values = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("Q5:R7").getValues();
  [id] = values[0];
  [estNum, v] = values[1];
  [negoNotes] = values[2];
  estNum = Number(estNum.split(" ")[1]); // If you want to use "estNum = Number(sh.getRange('Q6').getValue().split(" ")[1]);", please use this line.
  var sh2 = sh.getSheetByName('NegotiationData');
  var ids = sh2.getRange("A1:O1").getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<ids[0].length; i++) {
    if (ids[0][i] == id) {
      var temp = sh2.getRange(1, i + 1, sh2.getLastRow(), 3).getValues();
      for (var j=temp.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
        if (temp[j].join("") != "") {
          sh2.getRange(j + 2, i + 1, 1, 3).setValues([[v, estNum, negoNotes]]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike, Firstly thanks for taking the time out for my query. Your modified script works as I wanted.
Can you help with a minor issue in the modified code. I need the code to find last row under every Users' section. The problem is the script is pasting data under a user skipping the empty rows above.

 I'm sorry to confuse you with my sample sheet example. 1) I wanted just the numeric value extracted from the word "Estimate 1" which is in Q6. 2) I want the entire Story ID as is from R6. I'm using estNum that you have commented to achieve the above. Thanks Again!

Comment: @Zatin Dharmapuri I'm sorry for my incomplete answer. I updated my answer. Please confirm it. If that is not what you want, please tell me.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, 
Bang On!!! Oh no don't be sorry you made my day and I thank you for it.
You have a great day.

Comment: @Zatin Dharmapuri Thank you for your reply. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this does not resemble your code. Sorry about that. I'm learning too. But I'm putting it up anyway to provide an alternative method that includes finding the last row of the appropriate column...

```
function submitNegotiation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var negotiationData = ss.getSheetByName('NegotiationData');

  // Sheet1 variables
  var user = sheet1.getRange('Q5').getValue();
  var storyId = Number(sheet1.getRange('R6').getValue().split("-")[1]);
  var estimateNum = sheet1.getRange('Q6').getValue();
  var note = sheet1.getRange('Q7').getValue();
  var pointers = [storyId, estimateNum, note];

  // NegotiationData variables
  var range = negotiationData.getDataRange().getValues();
  var columns = negotiationData.getLastColumn();  
  var users = negotiationData.getRange(1, 1, 1, columns).getValues();


  for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

    // match user with users to get column number
    if(users[0][i] == user) {
      var col = negotiationData.getRange(1, i + 1).getColumn();

      // count rows in col
      var rowCount = 1;
      for(var i = 1; i < range.length; i++) {
        if (range[i][col - 1] != "") {
          rowCount++;
        }
      }

      // assign pointers
      var newRow = rowCount + 1;
      for(var j = 0; j < pointers.length; j++) {
        negotiationData.getRange(newRow, col, 1, 1).setValue(pointers[j]);
        col++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey,
I really appreciate your help on this but before I tried your solution this morning I gave Taranike's edited code a try and it worked as intended. I'm sure you'll master writing scripts soon. Thanks for your try.