# Google App Script: Copy & delete a row depending on a cell value to another Tab of the Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to build a script on my own, and did lots of research and tried a lot of code. The one from the [question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506703/google-apps-script-copyto-from-one-tab-to-another-tab-when-the-data-met-criteri)  seemed very promising, but I got an error which I could not solve.

**The Problem:**
I want to copy all data from *Sheet "Wunschliste"* of a row to a *sheet "Bestellt"*, on which in Colum A2:A in *sheet "Wunschliste"* is marked as "2 bestellt"( This is filled via a drop down. ).All data from *Sheet "Wunschliste"* which is marked as "2 bestellt" shall be deleted.

As this sheet is constantly filled with data, I want to use it as a archive, so all new entries which fullfil the criteria, need to be put under the last entry.

The sheet "Wusnchliste" got a header row and The date is filled in the column  A : M. This is why I don't need to copy the whole sheet.

The code I tried:

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo3() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Wunschliste');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Bestellt');
  const values = sourceRange.getValues().flatMap(([, b, c, d, , , , , i, j, k, l]) => l == "2 bestellt" ? [[b, c, d, i, j, k]] : []);
  console.log(values)
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

The Error I got:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> copyRowsWithCopyTo3 @ Code.gs:8

Can someone help me out here?

I read these articles, too (and modified them to test):
[Google Script: Copy row from one sheet to another depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222804/google-script-copy-row-from-one-sheet-to-another-depending-on-value)

[Copy and paste a row based on a cell's value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71727327/copy-and-paste-a-row-based-on-a-cells-value)

[Google Script to Match cell value and copy Paste related data in different tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904184/google-script-to-match-cell-value-and-copy-paste-related-data-in-different-tab)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have tested it works OK, it only returns this error when you don't have any matching value in column L. You could wrap your last part of the function in an if statement:

```
    if(values.length>0){
        targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
```

You can also add at the end an option to delete the source rows:

```
function copyRowsWithCopyTo3() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Wunschliste');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:L" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Bestellt');
  let origvalues = sourceRange.getValues()

  const values = origvalues.flatMap(([, b, c, d, , , , , i, j, k, l]) => l == "2 bestellt" ? [[b, c, d, i, j, k]] : []);
  console.log(values)
  if(values.length>0){
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  for (i=origvalues.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if (origvalues[i][11]=="2 bestellt"){sourceSheet.deleteRow(i+2)}
  }

}
```

Comment: Hey Martin,

thank you for your answer! 

My matching value is in A, so there must be the  mistake.
I am not sure what to change, so the value will be searched in A. I assume its something with the last bit of the phrase?
  const values = origvalues.flatMap(([, b, c, d, , , , , i, j, k, l]) => l == "2 bestellt" ?

I would change the => l == to => A == "2 bestellt"?

Comment: So I testes your code and changed the value coulun L just to see if this would work, but it does not copy the data to the "Bestellt" tab. it now recognizes the right lines, but it does not copy or delete it.

Comment: Ah I found the error on that. I had some cells with a data validation drop down where it tried to copy it at. I deleted this and now the function will copy the rows with " 2 bestellt" in Column L. It also deltes the rows now. Thank you very much!!

I only would need to understand, where in the code I can change the value  coulumn from "L" to "A" or any other. Could you tell me that? Thank you agian!

Comment: I'm glad! In the last line, 11 is the index of L, the 12thv letter of the alphabet. Change it to another number(A=0,B=1...)

Comment: And yes, change that L to A of your first question too !

Comment: Thank you! I was able to chenge it for the phrase to delte the rows, but couldn't change it for the part to copy it. Sorry, Martin, but can you help again?

I needed to change the range of the sheet, because we needed an extra column. so the whole range of the function needs to change. 

I changed:
`  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:M" + sourceSheet.getLastRow()); `

Comment: And for the valures checked in colum "M"

  const values = origvalues.flatMap(([, b, c, d, , , , , , , i,  k, l, m]) => m == "2 bestellt" ? [[b, c, d, i, j, k, l]] : []);

what did I miss?

Comment: Have you changed in the last if statement?: origvalues[i][11] with origvalues[i][12] ?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the script as we where discussing and it worked! I also was able to add this scrip in the menu bar.

there is one thing I still struggle with:

After I put all the Data form the "Wunschliste" to the "Bestellt" Tab, i need to be able to do the same thing with the data in the "Bestellt" tab, so if I mark the status *"Ist angekommen"* I want to be able to trigger the script via the menu to copy and delete these Data to the Tab "Angekommen". Each of the scripts are working for its own. But when I am putting it together, it always says the scrip "function copyRowsWithCopyT05" cannot be found.

```
    function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('WUNSCHLISTE BEREINIGEN')
      .addItem('Bestellte Artikel übertragen', 'copyRowsWithCopyTo3')
      .addItem('Gelieferte Artikel archivieren', 'copyRowsWithCopyTo5')
      .addToUi();}

function copyRowsWithCopyTo3() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Wunschliste');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:N" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Bestellt');
  let origvalues = sourceRange.getValues()
 
  const values = origvalues.flatMap(([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h , i, j, k, l, m, n]) => n == "Ja - ist bestellt" ? [[b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l,m]] : []);
  console.log(values)
  if(values.length>0){
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  for (i=origvalues.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if (origvalues[i][13]=="Ja - ist bestellt"){sourceSheet.deleteRow(i+2)}
}
function copyRowsWithCopyTo5() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Bestellt');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("A2:M" + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Angekommen');
  let origvalues = sourceRange.getValues()

    const values = origvalues.flatMap(([ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h , i,j, k, l, m, n]) => l == "Ist angekommen" ? [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]] : []);
  console.log(values)
  if(values.length>0){
  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  for (i=origvalues.length-1;i>=0;i--){
    if (origvalues[i][12]=="Ist angekommen"){sourceSheet.deleteRow(i+2)} 
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Ah I was missing a } - now it works!